# How to create regular expression to substitute strings surrounded by parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to substitute all chars inside `()` alongside with what's inside them but there is a problem. In the output it leaves whitespaces at start and end.

**Code:**

```
import re
regex = r"\(.+?\)"

test_str = ("(a) method in/to one's madness\n"
    "(all) by one's lonesome\n"
    "(as) tough as (old boot's)\n"
    " (at) any moment (now)   \n"
    "factors (in or into or out)        \n"
    " right-to-life\n"
    "all mouth (and no trousers/action)\n"
    "(it's a) small world\n"
    "  throw (someone) a bone ")

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Result:

```
    method in/to one's madness
 by one's lonesome
 tough as 
  any moment    
factors         
 right-to-life
all mouth 
 small world
  throw  a bone
```

I tried different patterns (other than this) to remove the `\s` from start but then when it finds the space at the end of any line it combines the following lines to the preceding one's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

Comment: You could also use `lstrip` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and `rstrip` to remove white spaces to the left and right of the resulting string.

Comment: Use `regex = r"\s*\([^()]*\)"` and `re.sub(regex, subst, test_str).strip()`

Comment: @anubhava didn't worked

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't worked

Comment: @Mujtaba: See if this works for you: https://regex101.com/r/OAizpn/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
regex = r"[^\S\r\n]*\([^()]*\)"
result = "\n".join([x.strip() for x in re.sub(regex, "", test_str).splitlines()])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HfVSZz)

The `[^\S\r\n]*\([^()]*\)` regex will remove all instances of

- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces and then
- `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`

The `"\n".join([x.strip() for x in re.sub(regex, "", test_str).splitlines()])` part splits all text into lines, strips them from leading/trailing whitespace and joins them back with a line feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `/\(([^)]+)\)/g`
So basically:

- `\(`: matches the opening parenthesis
- `([^)]+`: matches a group of characters
- `\)`: matches the closing parenthesis
- `/g`: all matches

User you `re.sub(...)` to replace all the regex matches.